# How to prevent CsvMapper from including unrecognized fields in the output CSV?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

When using `CsvMapper` with `@JsonPropertyOrder`, all fields that are not explicitly named are put at the end of the CSV record. This means that typos result in different CSV ordering.

Example:

```
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    final CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    System.out.println(csvMapper.writerWithSchemaFor(MyClass.class).writeValueAsString(new MyClass("test", true, 2)));
  }

  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @JsonPropertyOrder({"name", "code"})
  public static class MyClass {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private boolean status;

    @JsonProperty("code")
    private Integer code;
  }
}
```

Results in: `test,2,true`. Since `status` was not explicitly named in `@JsonPropertyOrder` it was put in the end of the record. I would prefer if `CsvMapper` threw an exception or if it was not serialized at all.

Another example would be if I changed `@JsonPropertyOrder` above to `@JsonPropertyOrder({"name", "stats", "code"})`. Notice the typo in `stats`. This would result in the same CSV as above.

How can I configure `CsvMapper` to either fail on unrecognized properties or not serialize properties not named in `@JsonPropertyOrder`?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the only purpose of `@JsonPropertyOrder` is to give you a chance of defining an order of your properties. Regarding the unspecified fields you could only use the `alphabetic` attribute to control their ordering. Consequently the annotation ignores typos and just cares about the known field names you've specified in its value attribute.

If you need a more granular control of active fields for (de-)serialization you could use [`@JsonIgnoreProperties`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.java) on your class or [`@JsonIgnore`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.java) on your fields.

May be this analogy is helpful: Consider an SQL statement – you `SELECT` the rows in a table and `ORDER` the result set afterwards. Here the `ORDER` command has also no influence on the result set's length or width.